# What is a Companion Score™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with **Score** version puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word could be calculated score with a specific metric, I call the score as a **Companion Score™**.
Use the following examples below to find the metric.

$$
% (purpose-specific template, not for general use)
%
\def\Pad{\P{2.0}}
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\textbf{ Example Words }\Pad}\def\NT{\textbf{ Companion Score}^{\;™}\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{Conifers modified 2019.9.9}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  OBJECTIVE }&\text{ 0 }\\ \hline
\text{  WHENEVER }&\text{ 0 }\\ \hline
\text{  COUNTEREXAMPLE }&\text{ 0 }\\ \hline
\text{  OXYGEN }&\text{ 1 }\\ \hline
\text{  PERFECTION }&\text{ 2 }\\ \hline
\text{  HIJACK }&\text{ 2 }\\ \hline
\text{  ZOOKEEPER }&\text{ 2 }\\ \hline
\text{  STUDENT }&\text{ 3 }\\ \hline
\text{  BATTLEFIELD }&\text{ 3 }\\ \hline
\text{  POSTPONE }&\text{ 4 }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Example Words,Companion Score™
OBJECTIVE,0
WHENEVER,0
COUNTEREXAMPLE,0
OXYGEN,1
PERFECTION,2
HIJACK,2
ZOOKEEPER,2
STUDENT,3
BATTLEFIELD,3
POSTPONE,4
```

**Open Bonus Question:**

What word you could find with the highest Companion Score™ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Companion Score is

> The number of pairs of adjacent letters in the word which are either the same or adjacent in the alphabet.

Examples

> PERFECTION has 'FE' and 'ON', so scores 2.
>  ZOOKEEPER has 'OO' and 'EE', so scores 2
>  STUDENT has 'ST', 'TU' and 'DE', so scores 3.

Bonus question

> The largest Companion Score I have attained is **7** with the following examples:
>  FIDDLEDEEDEE, NONCONSTITUTIONAL and NONOPPOSITION

Comment: You answered so fast... :P. Need to make it harder next time!